# How to check if data already exists in firebase entry?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I have the following entries in a large firebase database:

```
{
  "users": {
    "-KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHCvO": {
      "fName": "Peter",
      "ID": "U1EL9SSUQ",
      "username": "peter01"
    },
    "-KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHCvO": {
      "fName": "John",
      "ID": "U1EL5623",
      "username": "john.doe"
    }
  }, ..//millions of other entries
}
```

What would be the most efficient way of checking if the entry `{"fName":"Peter", "ID": "U1EL9SSUQ","username": "peter01"}`is already in the database? Does firebase have a built in way of checking this without having to loop through all the entries. The only efficient method I can think of doing this is hashing the JSON entry, and then storing all of the JSON entries under the subtree corresponding to this hashed value. Is there another way? Thanks.

Comment: What you're describing is indeed the common approach. You cannot ensure uniqueness of values under a location easily. But if you instead convert the values into keys, they're unique by definition. It's one of the common things that is different about the Firebase NoSQL database: you end up building your own indexes to ensure unique values, which a SQL database might do under the hood for you when you define a column to be unique.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you post this answer as a code example? I have a hard time transpiling the logic into code